# How to change all numbers to be in Arabic in Windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, regional-settings, arabic

I want to change all numbers in arabic in windows server 2003, not only currency

[image]

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but isn't that exactly what is known as arabic numerals? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals

Comment: Perhaps this is of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582629/how-to-ensure-rendering-of-digits-as-arabic-numerals-on-windows-10

Comment: @AndreasHartmann, yes you're right. Historically speaking, what we use in most European languages is Arabic numbers. And ironically, what most Arabic countries use is Indian numbers. However, in spoken language, they commonly "incorrectly" call the first set Foreign numbers, and the second set Arabic numbers. So yes, the OP wants Windows to use Indian numbers for all numbers just like it does for currency.

Comment: If you click on the **Customize** button, do you see a field called **Standard digits**?

Comment: @RacilHilan that **Standard dgits** is already assigned arabic numbers

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid that's all you can do. Some users have reported for many years on different versions of Windows that this happens if you don't set your interface language to Arabic. Understandably, setting the interface language to Arabic is not a good option, especially for the server like in your case. Some versions of Office are capable of using either numbering systems regardless of the settings in Windows, but I guess that's not what you're looking for. There could be some software out there that can do the trick, but I don't know any.